# How do I write better answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

I haven't written many answers, but after I have identified what the user is asking, I usually go with a conversational tone, going over whatever has a question mark over it and any context supporting it.

Optionally (if you have the time), recently [one of my answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/666062/the-direction-of-the-velocity-of-a-body-can-change-when-its-acceleration-is-cons/666067#666067) got downvoted. Any flaws and anything to improve my answer will help.

Comment: Downvotes pretty much happen everyone from time to time.  It's impossible to make the entire internet happy at the same time.  As long as your overall score is generally up, don't let this bother you.

Comment: Small fact : every single YouTube music video I have seen has a *minimum* of about 1%-2% of dislikes regardless of how brilliant the recording is within a specific genre.  You can't please some people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at your [reputation tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/273460/reet-jaiswal?tab=reputation), this seems to be only the second downvote you’ve received after a year on the site.

I’ll let other folks comment on the specifics of your answer (which also has an upvote). But I’ll offer this general advice: don’t worry very much about a single vote one way or the other. The more you write, the more you’ll be able to look for patterns in the ways that people respond to you. But people use the voting tools in lots of different ways, only some of which are scrutable. Don’t let a single vote sway you very far one way or the other.

Comment: I suppose that answers my question, and I was also being a bit paranoid about it.

Answer (score 0):

I just read your answer to which you linked.  It looks great to me, so I just upvoted it.

Your answer is clear, informative, helpful, and easy to read.  All are attributes of a quality answer.

My only very minor recommendation is to be cautious about phrases like *"if you are confused about this"*.  Because tone is very hard to detect online, that phrase can either be read as either:

- *"This is naturally a bit confusing, so please allow me to help further."*  - This is what I believe you intended.
- *"You're an ignorant fool, so if you're *still* confused, here's even more help for your tiny brain."* - I'm exaggerating in a humorous way here, but my point is that such a phrase *can* be considered condescending if the reader is not aware of your good intention.

Since the rest of your answer is 100% helpful, I would find it a bit odd if someone had the second interpretation.  Still, it's worth being mindful of how expressions like these can be perceived.

I look forward to reading more answers from you in the future.

Comment: Thanks, and I will continue writing more answers(yes I certainly meant for the first interpretation to come through:D)

Answer (score 0):

I have upvoted, but still, one criticism of the answer is that you referred to an explicit basis when explaining ( cartesian). But otherwise, I think is certainly valuable.

Comment: I see. Explaining with the help of a familiar example that can be easily visualised felt more natural to me from which we can generalise of course, but also I'm not skilled enough in other coordinate systems.